# XRDP login failed for display 0

Tags: ubuntu

I created a new user, set the password but not able to login via XRDP. The user/password are set correctly because I can ssh into the machine.

The error I'm getting is the same as in this question: [xrdp session: Login failed for display 0](https://superuser.com/questions/1143359/xrdp-session-login-failed-for-display-0)

I checked /etc/xrdp/sesman.ini and everything looks OK.

```
TerminalServerUsers=tsusers
TerminalServerAdmins=tsadmins
; When AlwaysGroupCheck=false access will be permitted
; if the group TerminalServerUsers is not defined.
AlwaysGroupCheck=false
```

I'm able to log in OK using my regular username & password so I'm guessing the AlwaysGroupCheck option works. For good measure I created the tsusers & tsadmins groups and add the new user to them, then restarted the xrdp service but still not able to login.

Host is Windows7, target is Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Maybe it is time you accept your own answer...` :-)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I restarted the machine and I noticed that I'm no longer getting the `xrdp session: Login failed for display 0` error. I suspect that creating the tsusers group and adding the new user to it, then restarting the xrdp service might've work but I probably did not notice because there was an additional problem with the window manager.

This should work:

```
#create the user
sudo adduser --home /home/<username>/ <username>
#create the groups
sudo addgroup tsusers
sudo addgroup tsadmins
#Add the new user to the xrdp group
sudo adduser <username> tsusers
#Restart the service
sudo service xrdp restart
```

Comment: thanks bro this fix my issue I had same using centoOS 7 with MATE .

Comment: That helped a lot.  Thanks!

Comment: note that after adding those groups root login will not work unless root is also added to them